# Executing Stored Procedure using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a procedure named as Get_Added_Request_ID and using this procedure I need to get returned the Request_ID value (VARCHAR2). I have referrd plenty of docs released by Oracle and Microsoft but still I could not find a good solution may be because I am a new learner for Oracle and ASp.NET. Please someone help me in this issue. Thanks in advance
[image]

> -- Parameter   Type      Mode  Default?
>   -- ATTR_       VARCHAR2  IN
>   -- REQUEST_ID  VARCHAR2  OUT

Answer (score 1):

Please view this [link](http://%20https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-oracle-stored-procedures-from-microsoft-net/) for the documentation on how to connect to oracle by using oracle data provider

You should use oracle data provider from this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) for connecting oracle.

the example code for your scenario will be

```
Using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Data;

namespace CallingOracleStoredProc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (OracleConnection objConn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=*your datasource*; User ID=*Your UserID*; Password=*Your Password*"))
            {
                OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();
                objCmd.Connection = objConn;
                objCmd.CommandText = "Get_Added_Request_ID";
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                objCmd.Parameters.Add("ATTR_", OracleType.NVarChar).Value = "test";
                objCmd.Parameters.Add("REQUEST_ID", OracleType.NVarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                try
                {
                    objConn.Open();
                    objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    System.Console.WriteLine("The Request ID is {0}", objCmd.Parameters["REQUEST_ID"].Value);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}",ex.ToString());
                }

                objConn.Close();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to check whether the value of Request_ID is stored or parsed?

Comment: I have edited the typos in the above answer. The Request_ID will be the output for the above code and it can be get by using objCmd.Parameters["REQUEST_ID"].Value, it will return the value of   REQUEST_ID param of Get_Added_Request_ID stored procedure

Comment: thanks for the edit. Can you tell me where should I add the above code? In which folder in web API project?

Answer (score 0):

use execute scalar which return 1 row - 1 column value & store it in appropriate variable
For e.g :- SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(_connectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Get_Added_Request_ID", null);

note :- ExecuteScalar is came from nuget Microsoft.Application Block